# Apache redirect problems

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I thought this redirect would work but its not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.sub\.my-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.my-domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

It suppose to work like:

```
*.sub.my-domain.com -> sub.my-domain.com
123.sub.my-domain.com -> sub.my-domain.com
asdf.sub.my-domain.com -> sub.my-domain.com
```

Comment: If you change the `$0` in the `RewriteRule` to a `$1` it should then change `123.sub.my-domain.com` to `sub.my-domain.com/123`. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, I just want all subdomains of `*.sub.my-domain.com` to redirect `sub.my-domain.com`. For example: `www.sub.my-domain.com` redirects to `sub.my-domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with virtual host containers as it won't require any additional parsing to work.

Redirect everything to `sub.my-domain.com` while preserving any path

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.sub.my-domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://sub.my-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you have the normal virtual host container for `sub.my-domain.com`.

If you want to do it with rewrite, you'll need this. It checks whether the host is right and redirects if it's not

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: ok i had some problems at the beginning because of my reverse dns but now all fixed and working